# Embedding executed Jupyter notebook in rst-based documentation

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I would like to embed a Jupyter notebook in an RST file. Preferably, this notebook can be interactive, but it can at least be seen. It would also be nice if these notebooks could be executed in the documentation build, but I don't know if that is possible.

I am not looking for a solution that would not involve having the notebook embedded in an rst file -- I know that nbsphinx can build documentation from ipynb files, but that is not what I am looking for.

Thank you!

Comment: You want what nbsphinx does, but you don't want to use nbsphinx? What is wrong with using nbsphinx for your use case?

Comment: @StevePiercy no, nbsphinx does not let you embed a notebook inside an rst -- it just turns a notebook into an html file

Comment: I think you do not understand what an .rst file is for. reStructuredText is intended to be rendered to HTML, PDF, and other supported formats by Sphinx and its extensions, including nbsphinx. By itself, reStructuredText does not allow one to "embed a Jupyter notebook in an RST file".

Comment: If `nbsphinx` doesn't do what you want, you can look for alternatives at https://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/links.html. In your case maybe https://github.com/ngoldbaum/RunNotebook would be relevant?